# Running out of hard drive space, yet Disk Inventory shows only 190GB used vs. 480 GB used in HD Get Info? How is that possible?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I'm down to 20GB on a 500GB hard drive and would like to know what's eating up the disk space, so I can clear out any large things I no longer need.

2 screen shots are showing me Disk Inventory results and my Storage report in "About This MAC"

[image]
[image]

The MAC HD is showing 347GB "OTHER" space being used, whereas DISK INVENTORY is showing only 190GB Total used.  What am I missing or don't understand about what Disk Inventory is doing/showing, and how can I find significant files eating up the 347GB that isn't videos, photos?

Comment: Did you run DiskInventory as a user with Admin rights? Do you have local TimeMachine "backups" enabled?

Comment: Additionally, have you run a repair disk process on the disk in question with disk utility to verify space is not being misreported?

Comment: didn't know about the Disk Inventory with Admin rights. Not sure how to do that differently from what I did. So, the answer is "NO."
I did run a "repair permissions" if that's what you mean and that didn't seem to change anything. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Time Machine local backups

If you use Time Machine, my guess is that the discrepancy is from [local backups](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427). If so, you can free up that space by connecting your Time Machine drive and running letting Time Machine complete a backup.

Once you have done that, you might want to disable local backups by issuing this command in Terminal.app:

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

but keep in mind that the local backups are meant to provide a safety net for those times when your Time Machine drive is not attached.

#### If the cause is not Time Machine, try OmniDiskSweeper

If that is not it, I recommend using [OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidisksweeper/download/) to check your drive space.

ODS is a free app, and works very simply. When you launch ODS, it will show you a "Drive List" showing all of the available drives. Choose your main hard drive and then it will start searching.

The results are shown in a very simple column format, similar to the Finder. The largest folders will bubble to the top, and will let you see exactly where your disk space has gone.

#### Using OmniDiskSweeper as root

ODS will only calculate the sizes of the folders that you can read. 99% of the time, that should show you the problem.

However, if you want to be sure that you are seeing *everything* you can launch the app as root using this command:

```
sudo /Applications/OmniDiskSweeper.app/Contents/MacOS/OmniDiskSweeper
```

BUT BE VERY VERY CAREFUL WHEN DOING THIS, since ODS will allow you to delete files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not Time Machine local snapshots. Those would show up in System Information's About This Mac pane, but it lists Backups as Zero KB.

Comment: I ran ODS and it came up with about 20GB more than Disk Inventory, just over 200GB, which still leaves a big difference. I uploaded the screen shot to this webpage as comparison.

http://www.workplacecommunicationexpert.com/macbook-hard-drive-images/