# My Macbook Pro Retina 15" has a 250G H/D which is full. How do I identify what I can remove

Tags: macbook-pro

In The about this MAC- under storage- thedrive is full. The colour bar named "other" takes up 170G. I want to clean my hard drive to open up some operating space

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my startup disk so full?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162282/why-is-my-startup-disk-so-full)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I free up some disk space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/860/how-can-i-free-up-some-disk-space)

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally recommend using a tool like [DaisyDisk](http://daisydiskapp.com/) to get a clear indication of what files are taking up the most space.

[image: Daisydisk Screenshot]

After that you could also run a tool like CleanMyMac (paid) or MacClean (free) to help you delete more hidden files like browser caches and language files.

Answer (score 0):

Download the app called Disk Inventory X. It will map out your entire drive and you can easily visualize what's taking up the most space. Also, the app is free!

Here's a screenshot:
[image]